# interop.scripting.dll not found - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dll, typelib

I wonder if this is some sort of reference issue in Visual Studio Express 2013. I am building from source so none of these files should have to be registered after the fact. Upon running the type library from the bin folder in an external program as a custom command, it returns the interop.scripting.dll not found error. What could be causing this? Does it matter that some reference paths for COM files point to the obj folder and not bin (I think this is normal)?

Example references (I can't post images yet) --
    C:\FNNTQuarterlyReports\SourceCode\obj\Debug\Interop.esriSystemUtility.dll
    C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\DotNet\ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.dll
    C:\FNNTQuarterlyReports\SourceCode\obj\Debug\Interop.Scripting.dll
    c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Basic 2005 Power      Packs\3.0\Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.dll

Comment: Did you register your assembly with `regasm /codebase`?

Comment: I built this locally, not from another machine. Also, copy-local is set to True for the com files. But I did, just as a test, register the tlb from the bin folder I created with regasm -- it does nothing.

Comment: Is there an Interop.Scripting.dll file in the bin folder to which you are building?

Comment: What .Net framework are you using? 4.0 , 4.0 Client profile,...

Comment: Using the 3.5 Framework. The Interop.Scripting.dll file is indeed in the bin folder.

Comment: I should add, though I'm not sure if it matters -- the source is from elsewhere. I had to migrate the tool, fix up all the references (even install vb powerpack) and resolve a bug, which I believe I identified (string-date conversion issue since the system uses mm-dd-yyy format). It's pretty much done, but I can't debug with this issue.

Comment: Also I wonder if a "strong name" would make any difference, as I believe the interop.scripting dll is already wrapped automatically, so I've been reading.

Comment: [This might be a solution related to your DLL issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349343/net-exe-not-picking-dll-dependencies/33413718) also on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved. Not entirely sure of the details, but I started fresh with a backup copy  of the source and left the original .NET and COM references as-is. The key difference is the use of powerpacks.VS as opposed to the new 3.0, and older ESRI dlls (dating to 9.1 period). All had copy-local set to true. For some reason this build works fine... trying to modernize the references somehow messed things up, possibly due to a compatibility issue, or some other oversight. Thanks for the help.